# How to make my angularjs directive work on EDGE?

Tags: angularjs-directive, microsoft-edge

I have this directive which selects a table with specific ID and converts it to csv report, this is the code of the directive:

```
 myApp.directive('exportToCsv', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function stringify(str) {
                    return '"' + str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s*\s$/, '').replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
                }
                var el = element[0];
                element.bind('click', function (e) {


                    var elementResult = document.querySelector('#tabletarget');


                    /* var table = angular.element(document).find('#table-target'); */

                    var table = elementResult;


                    var csvString = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                        var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                        for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
                            if (rowData[j].innerHTML.indexOf('<a href') > -1) {
                                var ele = angular.element(rowData[j]);
                                for (var k = 0; k < ele[0].childNodes.length; k++) {
                                    if (ele[0].childNodes[k].tagName == 'A') {
                                        csvString = csvString + stringify(ele[0].childNodes[k].innerText) + ",";
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (rowData[j].innerHTML.indexOf('<em') > -1 || rowData[j].innerHTML.indexOf('<strong>') > -1) {
                                var ele = angular.element(rowData[j]);
                                csvString = csvString + stringify(ele[0].textContent) + ",";
                            } else {
                                csvString = csvString + stringify(rowData[j].innerHTML) + ",";
                            }
                        }
                        csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
                        csvString = csvString + "\n";
                    }
                    console.log(csvString);
                    csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
                    // alert(csvString);
                    var a = $('<a/>', {
                        style: 'display:none',
                        href: 'data:application/csv;base64,' + btoa(csvString),
                        download: 'export.csv'
                    }).appendTo('body')
                    a[0].click()
                    a.remove();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

In markup I place the button in html:

```
  <button export-to-csv class="form-control" >Download</button>
```

I suspect that document.querySelector is not supported in EDGE/IE?

What else can I use?

Working fine on chrome and mozilla.

In Edge's console i am getting NO error, and getting the correct output in console, but the download popup isn't showing, maybe the download needs a different handling for Edge?

Comment: {{gs("csvReportButton", "Get CSV report")}} is a completely different function, it just returns a string, it has nothing to do with this

Comment: You can check every feature you suspect of incompatibility in [known sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). And it's compatible with all modern browsers, that's why it's widely used. The question doesn't contain information on what exactly doesn't work. Consider providing clear problem statement and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: In console I am getting NO error, i am getting the correct output but the download pop up isn't being called, so the problem is in handling download i guess?

Comment: Edited my post to add clarification at the end.